# How do I close the current frame when clicking a button?

Tags: java, swing, oop, user-interface

I am trying to create a simple login form using Java. However, when I am trying to dispose the current frame, it doesn't work. Before, the JFrame frame = new JFrame() and JPanel panel = new JPanel() is located inside the public void Login(), but the frame isn't being recognized by the public void actionPerformed, so I put it outside of the public void Login(). After putting it outside, the actionPerformed can now recognize the frame, but the frame doesn't close whenever I click the button.

Here is my **Try.java** file:

```
public class Try {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoginForm LForm = new LoginForm();
        LForm.Login();
    }
}
```

Here is my **LoginForm.java** file:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class LoginForm implements ActionListener {
    
    private static JLabel Anum, Pass, Success;
    private static JTextField AccountNumTF;
    private static JPasswordField PassTF;
    private static JButton LoginBtn, CreateAccountBtn;
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    public void Login() {
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        
        panel.setLayout(null);
        
        Anum = new JLabel("Account Number: ");
        Anum.setBounds(10, 20, 125, 25);
        panel.add(Anum);
        
        AccountNumTF = new JTextField(20);
        AccountNumTF.setBounds(125, 20, 165, 25);
        panel.add(AccountNumTF);
        
        Pass = new JLabel("Password: ");
        Pass.setBounds(10, 50, 80, 25);
        panel.add(Pass);
        
        PassTF = new JPasswordField();
        PassTF.setBounds(125, 50, 165, 25);
        panel.add(PassTF);
        
        LoginBtn = new JButton("LOGIN");
        LoginBtn.setFocusable(false);
        LoginBtn.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD,12));
        LoginBtn.setBounds(20, 88, 75, 25);
        LoginBtn.addActionListener(new LoginForm());
        panel.add(LoginBtn);
        
        CreateAccountBtn = new JButton("Create an account");
        CreateAccountBtn.setFocusable(false);
        CreateAccountBtn.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD,12));
        CreateAccountBtn.setBounds(132, 88, 150, 25);
        panel.add(CreateAccountBtn);
        
        Success = new JLabel("Click the login button to test it");
        Success.setBounds(50, 125, 250, 25);
        panel.add(Success);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String UserACNum = AccountNumTF.getText();
        String UserPass = PassTF.getText();
        if (UserACNum.equals("Admin") && UserPass.equals("AdminPass")) {
            Success.setText("Login Successful!");
            Menu menu = new Menu();
            frame.dispose(); //It doesn't work

        }
        else {
            Success.setText("Login Failed!");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my **Menu.java** file:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Menu {
    JFrame Frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
    Menu() {
        Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Frame.setSize(500,500);
        Frame.setLayout(null);
        Frame.add(Panel);
        
        Frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate your response and thank you in advance.

Comment: Change this line: `LoginBtn.addActionListener(new LoginForm());` to this `LoginBtn.addActionListener(this);` Also, consider adopting [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html). Also, _Swing_ has many [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) which you should consider using.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! So because of the new LoginForm(), it created another object? Did I get that right? Sorry, I am new to Java and still trying to learn.

Comment: Yes, it created another object.

Comment: Thank you! How do I mark this post as answered or solved?

Comment: You don't, because I didn't post an answer. If you think other people will encounter the same problem as you and will find your question when searching the Internet, then you can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). If I were you, I would simply delete this question and continue on with the development of your _Swing_ application. Feel free to post another question if you hit a future snag in your development process.